# How to deploy a whole folder of manifests to Kubernetes with Skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold, kubernetes-jobs

I'm trying to implement the suggested parallel processing expansion job from Kubernetes documentation itself https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/

I have my expansion working, The `build-jobs.sh` is called on skaffold as a before hook.

[image: job expansion]

But once my jobs specs are generated, my Dockerfile is built, Skaffold is not deploying everything is inside `/k8s/jobs` folder.

My skaffold spec:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta2
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: my-job
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: MY_IMAGE_LOCATION
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hooks:
      before:
        - command: [ "sh", "-c", "./k8s/build-jobs.sh" ]
          os: [ darwin, linux ]

manifests:
  rawYaml:
      - ./k8s/jobs/*.yaml
```

My attempts with the `rawYaml` field:

- `./k8s/jobs`
- `./k8s/jobs/`

None of the above works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the following manifests yaml does the trick

```yaml
manifests:
  rawYaml:
      - ./k8s/jobs/*.yaml
```